# Load / Get a block outside of Magento routing for external use

Tags: magento-enterprise, blocks, enterprise-1.13

I have an external webpage and I'm trying to pull the site header block from the Magento framework to use as a header in this external page. This is what I have so far:

```
// initialize Magento
$rootPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$mageInc = $rootPath . "/app/Mage.php";
include_once $mageInc;

Mage::app('admin')->setCurrentStore(0);

$headerBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_header');
//also tried
//$headerBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_header', 'header');
```

Execution stops there, however, and I get no error messages. My goal is to pull block `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header`, which I think I can use to load `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">` and all its contents from the page.xml layout file. That XML tag is wrapped inside

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
  <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/1column.phtml">
```

tags, so maybe I need to specify that somehow? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and where to go from here.

Comment: this code works but i have a problem with the logout button, some one have te same issue? Regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the secret ingredient.. and it is `Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');`

```
<?php
include_once "app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default');
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

//get the loaded head and header blocks and output
$headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
echo $headBlock->toHtml() . $headerBlock->toHtml();
```

Thanks @benmarks!

Answer (score 3):

You're 99% there. You need to call toHtml() on the block, and then echo it out to see the result:

```
<?php
// initialize Magento
$rootPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$mageInc = $rootPath . "/app/Mage.php";
include_once $mageInc;

Mage::app('admin')->setCurrentStore(0);

echo $headerBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_header')->toHtml();
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and nothing. This is the answer though, I tried it on a new install and it works. Thanks.

Comment: I got this code working, however it doesn't give me near anything that the site header has. The site header has several logos, menus, and links. This gives me a one of the many images in the header. Perhaps I'm not loading it correctly?