# Using magento header and footer files outside magento in simple php file

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

I want to use magento header and footer files(custom theme) in my custom php file. How can I get header and footer. php file location is root folder.

I am using this code

```
require("app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

$headerBlock = $layout->createBlock('page/html_header')->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml');
$currencyBlock = $layout->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('currency/currency.phtml');
$headerBlock->setChild('currency_selector', $currencyBlock);
echo $headerBlock = $headerBlock->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need call design area  **`Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');`** at your script.

```
<?php
include_once "app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default');
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

//get the loaded head and header blocks and output
$headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
echo $headBlock->toHtml() . $headerBlock->toHtml();
```

get footer

```
$footerBlock = $layout->getBlock('footer');
echo $footerBlock->toHtml();
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: I want to use also session here also like user login/cart item how can I do this.

Comment: I have added this line and my session also working.

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

Comment: hope my help works.

Comment: I am getting url issue with this. for wishlist and logout 
Getting Url:
http://www.example.com/customfile.php/wishlist/?___SID=U

but I want this url 
http://www.example.com/wishlist/?___SID=U
How can i get this

Comment: please check updated answer for footer.

Comment: I am getting url problem with all of link my custom file also include in url I don't want this. How can I set this

Comment: ok i am trying and give you update as soon as possible. i am trying this but didn't find any error.

Comment: How can load theme layout outside of magento?  Above code loads default layout.

Answer (score 3):

Pushpendra Singh ,As @denish says,You  have missed to call  design area  as  fronted *`Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');`*

Also,You have call the layout then  ***no need to create blocks*** `('page/html_header','directory/currency')` again using `page/html_header`, etc if it is `already called at  your design area`.Just need to loaded those blocks `using getBlock('');`

```
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
```

etc.If want to add new add block which does not ,you frontend area section  then use createBlock()  AND setChild FOR ADD  ON EXITING LAYOUT

see more code at https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5080

Comment: i have call it out Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');. don't get dummy credit. tell true to all one. this is not for reputation you want. i am giving answer to help not for reputation as you.

Comment: I have just put my point of view on basic of  question.

Comment: Sorry, denish ,i was said the text `As @denish says.. . frontend' ` for    Pushpendra Singh not for you. sorry for if it heart you.I do not take u credit .. This credit goes to all  for this answered.May be my English  make wrong meaning at   u.Also remember  once thing my friend  that i have wrote answered at Mse not for reputation and it my hobby to answer here and i love it.If your thought about me " this is not for reputation you want" Then it totally wrong and i have no reason for u at this case.

Comment: ok buddy.......!!!